# How to build a one command compile project by cmake which have submodules?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project like this:

```
(base) [tp]➜  ~ tree cmake_test
cmake_test
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── mycode.cpp
├── sub1
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── somecode.cpp
└── sub2
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── src
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── somecode2.cpp
```

which i want to build a project cmake_test, it has two submodules - `sub1` and `sub2`, and its own build target `src`

`sub1 and sub2` are library maker, which means their build targets is some dll, then the `src(mycode.cpp)`  part need this dll to build a executable file.

so, in the first `CMakeLists.txt`, i do like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)                                                                                                                   
project(cmake_test)
add_subdirectory(sub1 sub1_src)
add_subdirectory(sub2 sub2_src)
add_subdirectory(src my_src)
```

and in `sub1/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)                                                                                                                   
project(sub1)
add_subdirectory(src sub1_src1)
```

and in `sub1/src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)                                                                                                                   
add_library(somecode SHARED somecode.cpp)
install(TARGETS somecode LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
```

`src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

link_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
add_executable(mycode mycode.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${arg1} somecode)
# please notice here, src need to link somecode.so
# somecode is built from sub1, and install to ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
# so the update somdecode.so is placed after install sub1)                                                                                                             
install(TARGETS mycode RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})
```

the problem happens when i type: `make install` in cmake/build, because the compile order is:

***sub1 make, sub2 make, src make, sub1 install, sub2 install, src install.***

please notice `src` make is in front of `sub1` install. so, if i modify the sub1 code, then this make install is bad, because mycode use the old `sub1` code.

So, how can i make this work?

Comment: How does cmake know that src uses sub1?

Comment: sub1 will install a library into a path, then the src build depend on this library, i give the library path to link_directories()

Comment: Show that code.

Comment: by the way the directories are irrelevant, you could have this problem all in one cmake file.

Comment: @user253751 thanks, added. and i want to make sub1 and sub2 independent because i may use it in other projects. it's like a common library

Comment: Why is it ${arg1}?

Comment: @sorry, i didnt get it, i dont have ${arg1}

Comment: "the problem happens when I type: `make install` in cmake/build, because the compile order is: ..." - I don't understand **why** the compile order is important in your case. What the **exact problem** (e.g. an error message) do you have with the given order?

Comment: @Tsyvarev because B is submodule of A, A's target need link library bulit from B, and the library will be update-to-date after make install in B, so, make install in A, will compile with order: make B, make A, install B, install A, so, make A will use the old library B, the correct order is : make B, install B, make A, install A

Comment: @nick yes you do, you have it in target_link_libraries

Comment: @Tsyvarev the exact problem is: make install build the executable file used the old library because the compile order.

Comment: "make A will use the old library B" - Still, I don't understand the problem. The executable `mycode` in the **build tree** uses (finds via RPATH mechanism) the library `somecode` located in the *build tree*. This is expected behavior. The same executable but in the **install tree** won't use the library in the *build tree*. Assuming you adjust RPATH properly, the **installed** executable should find *installed* library.

Comment: I think @user253751 answer nails it down. The `link_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})` command forces your build to use the libraries from the installation directory not from the build folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> link_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX})

You shouldn't need to do this. You should be able to just do:

> target_link_libraries(mycode somecode)

and cmake knows that the `mycode` program requires the `somecode` library and it will automatically build `somecode` before it links `mycode`.

If this doesn't automatically happen, then something else is wrong with the CMakeLists. It might be because you wrote `${arg1}` instead of `mycode`. Is `arg1` a variable that contains the word `mycode`?